# Archive the uiview controls (uiimageview,uiscrollview,uitableview,uibutton)

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios5

Am archive and unarchive the uiview and display the view in ipad  this  controls (uiimageview,uiscrollview,uitableview,uibutton) were not displayed....but uiview subviews all controls are there ....Is it possible to get that  controls(uiimageview,uiscrollview,uitableview,uibutton) in view? possible means how to get that controls to display in view.

uiview *viewForArchive;
    uiview *newCir=[uiview alloc ]initwithframe:cgrectmake(0,0,768,1024)];

//archiving

```
  NSMutableData *d= [NSMutableData data];
  NSKeyedArchiver *kA=[[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:d];
       [kA encodeObject:newCir  forKey:@"view"];
      [kA finishEncoding];

    if ([d writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory()   stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archiveView"] options:NSAtomicWrite  error:nil] == NO) 
    {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error");

    }
    else 
    {


        NSLog(@"Written!");
    }
    //unarchiving
    NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"archiveView"]];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *decoder = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:theData];
    NSDictionary *dict=  [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"view"];
    [decoder finishDecoding];
    if ([theData writeToFile:[NSHomeDirectory()  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"unarchiveView"] options:NSAtomicWrite  error:nil] == NO) {
        NSLog(@"writeToFile error");

    }
    else {

        if ([dict isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {

          viewForArchive=(UIView *)dict;
            NSLog(@"view:%@",viewForArchive.subviews );
           viewForArchive.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
         [self.view addsubview:viewForArchive];
       }   
        NSLog(@"Written!");

     }
```

this is the uiview archiver coding....

In this coding to print the  viewForArchive.subviews all controls are there....in my application this controls  (uiimageview,uiscrollview,uitableview,uibutton) were not displayed...what is the problem in this coding...

Comment: I cant able to get u can send code or be clear about question?

Answer (score 1):

If your point is to save specific states of your objects, you can store strings in the NSUserDefaults and set the objects according to your strings. Alternatively, you can create the xib files, which automatically will store your objects?